# How to get all the attributes for a given contact key from data extension based on dataextensionid

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

We need to get all the attribute values for a given contact key from the data extension. We are trying to find it out via RESTAPI.

Is there a way to get all the attributes via dataextension id.

I am getting dataextension ID from the below call:

```
 Get
https://xxxxx.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/interaction/v1/eventDefinitions/{xxxxxx}
```

Sample response:

```
 {
"id": "xxxxx",
"type": "EmailAudience",
"name": "xxxxxx",
"description": "",
"createdDate": "2019-07-02T21:41:53.4",
"createdBy": 100169002,
"modifiedDate": "2019-07-02T21:41:53.4",
"modifiedBy": 100169002,
"mode": "Production",
"eventDefinitionKey": "DEAudience-xxxx",
"dataExtensionId": "xxxxxxx",
"dataExtensionName": "xxxxxxxxxx",
"sourceApplicationExtensionId": "xxxxxxxx",
"filterDefinitionId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
"filterDefinitionTemplate": "",
"iconUrl": "/images/icon-data-extension.svg",
"arguments":
Unknown macro: { "serializedObjectType"}
,
"configurationArguments":
Unknown macro: { "unconfigured"}
,
"metaData":
Unknown macro: { "criteriaDescription"}
,
"interactionCount": 1,
"isVisibleInPicker": false,
"isPlatformObject": false,
"category": "Audience",
"publishedInteractionCount": 1,
"automationId": "xxxxxxx"
}
```

There is the below call which can provide all the attributes of the contact. However, it's using the External Key of the data extension.

```
GET https://xxxxx.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/data/v1/customobjectdata/key/xxxxxx-xxxx-4E19-89DD-C583C2A732D7/rowset/
```